# MP4 Fast Forward/Rewind

Tags: directshow.net

I need help with implementing fast forward and rewind. I'm using directshow in c# and have played with IMediaSeeking however the results suck! SetRate does not work at all and SetPositions is choppy and apparently has sync issues with multiple threads so it ceases to run after the first time it's called. I played with Imediaposition but could not get it to work at all. My graph is simply

FileSourceAsync -> Intel Splitter -> MainConcept Decoder -> Decklink Render

After scanning the supported interfaces the filesource and decoder do not apparently support IMediaSeeking.

Does anybody have any ideas or clues that can help me fast forward and rewind an mp4 file in a directshow graph?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IMediaSeeking` works properly when underlying filter implement it properly. One of the filters you use (Intel's?) seems to be having issues with seeking. Perhaps you can replace it with a better alternative.